# How to get FlaskForm data using JQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, flask

I'm trying to send a jquery ajax request using the field data from a flask form. I can currently get something like this to work... to send the form data as an ajax request to my python code that's running behind the scenes.

**html**

```
<form id=test_form name="form_name">
  <input type="text" name="form_text">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
$(function() {
  $('form#test_form').bind('submit', function() {
    $.getJSON('/_ard_connect', {
      var1: $('input[name="form_text"]').val()
    }, function(data) {
      $("#some_result").text(data.result);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

**python**

```
@app.route('/_test_link')
def test_link():
    var1 = request.args.get('var1')
    answer = doSomething(var1)
    return jsonify( result=answer )
```

if I define a FlaskForm like this:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    test_form = StringField(label='tt')

myform = MyForm()
```

is it possible to pass something like `var1: $('{{ myform.test_form.data }} ').val()` to my getJSON function.

**alternative(?)**

I've also tired abstracting my ajax javascript and passing the form data as an argument

```
<form id=test_form action="javascript: somefunc('{{ ardu.port.data }}')">
```

but it will only get the default value...

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:**

You can't do this in javascript file. Instead you can do that in view render template file ( html )

***file.html***

```
var1: $('{{ myform.test_form.data }} ').val()
```

**Case 2:**

I think you are doing to update the action url based on some javascript function but this is also wrong. This `somefunc` can't execute itself in onload. Instead try `window.onload` method and execute the `somefunc` update the `test_form` url